# What factors should be considered to select jet-pipe or flapper-nozzle technology for a primary control surface?

Tags: flight-controls, control-surfaces, hydraulic-system

How is the servovalve mechanism chosen between these two mechanisms? what are their advantages and drawbacks?

Comment: "Which is better" questions are opinion based and will be closed. The "What factors" is the part that saves this one. You'd be well served to rewrite the whole question from that perspective.

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: It may be tough to find someone with enough experience in servo-valves to answer this, but I can add some (old) insight. The buyer of the valves typically won't be too concerned about the design. They want performance (size, weight, power, freq response, reliability, cost). I was involved in a study of these about 35 years ago. The end result was there was little difference in performance between them. The biggest difference we found was the jet pipe's failure modes to contamination were more benign but it wasn't enough to justify switching from the flapper style we had.